# Why is my php email script send an email to my spam not in my inbox?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code below. When I click "send email" button it works fine. But it doesn't appear to my Inbox... It was routed to Spam folder.

```
<?php require_once "../session.php" ?>
<?php
$host='localhost'; // My hostname
$username='root'; // Mysql username
$password='*********'; // Mysql password
$db_name='jobs'; // DB name

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name);
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "SEND CV NOW") {
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT JobTitle,JobID FROM tblebjobs WHERE ID='".$_GET['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . '<br />'. $insertstatement);
} 
$details = mysql_fetch_row($result);

//upload cv first
        if(!isset($_FILES['cv'])) {
            $err = "You forgot to select a CV to upload";
        }       
        $cvname = basename(stripslashes($_FILES['cv']['name']));

        if(empty($cvname)){
            $err = "The name of the attachment was not found.";
        }

        if(empty($err)){
            $newcv = "tempcv/".$cvname;
            $result = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], $newcv);
                if(empty($result)){
                    $err = "There was an error moving the uploaded cv please try again if it continues to file please call us directly.";
                } else {
                    //increment by 1
                    $sql3 = "update `emp_record` set `total_app`=`total_app` + 1 WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name']."'";
                    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
                    $sql2 = "update `tblebjobs` set `total_app`=`total_app` + 1 WHERE ID='".$_GET['id']."'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());

                    //create random for boundry
                    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
                    //set email headers
                    $headers = "Return-path: <".$email.">"."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Reply-to: <".$email.""."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"\r\n";
                    $headers .= "From: ".$email." <".$email.">"."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
                    $headers .= "X-Mailer: E-borders.net web site\r\n";
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $headers .= "\r\n\r\n";
                    //setup message and include $body previously prepped
                    $prebody = "--PHP-mixed-{$random_hash}\r\n";
                    $prebody .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
                    $prebody .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
                    $prebody .="\r\n";
                    $prebody .="A CV has been submitted from the website the CV is attached to this email and the details of the form submission are below.<br /><br />";
                    $prebody .="{$firstname} {$surname}<br />";
                    $prebody .="{$email}<br />";
                    $prebody .="\r\n";
                    $prebody .="--PHP-mixed-{$random_hash}\r\n";
                // prep attachments
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($newcv)));
                    $prebody .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"{$newcv}\"\r\n";
                    $prebody .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$newcv}\"\r\n";
                    $prebody .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
                    $prebody .= "{$data}\r\n\r\n";
                    $prebody .= "--PHP-mixed-{$random_hash}\r\n";
                    $prebody .= "\r\n";     
                    //set to address
                    $to  = 'jtcompanero@yahoo.com';
                    //set subject
                    $subject = "CV FROM: {$details[0]} ({$details[1]})";
                    // Mail it
                    mail($to, $subject, $prebody, $headers);
                    unlink($newcv);
                    $err = "Your CV has been submitted we will be in touch shortly";
                }
        }
}
?>

<u><strong>Apply Online</strong></u>
<?php if (isset($err)) {
    echo "<div style=\"text-align:center;color:red;font-weight:bold;\">$err</div>";
}?>
<p>
<form method="POST" action="apply.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr><td>First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" id+"lastname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Path to CV:</td><td><input type="file" name="cv" id="cv" /></td></tr>
</table>
<p align=center>
<input type="submit" name="action" id="action" value="SEND CV NOW">
</p>
</form>
</p>
</div>
```

In addition... I have CV attachment here. But the file wasn't added to message as well.

Comment: Depends on what your email provider thinks is spam. It sees the email isn't coming from where you say it is (the from address is probably different than the server it's being sent from for one) and thinks its spam.

Comment: is the from email address an actual email address? have you set the MX record for your Domain?

Comment: thee are books written on this subject as well as a hew hundred SO threads

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the content of your email (either in the body, or within the headers). Not the actual php code itself.

Spam filters work in different ways so it's not possible to give you a specific solution.

Note: try using a mail component like http://swiftmailer.org/ to send your emails, instead of constructing them with a large string.

Comment: +1 SPAM detection is so complex, that ensuring that your email doesn't get flagged as spam could easily be the subject of an entire book (see FAQ).